# Designing a portable makefile loop

Tags: c, loops, makefile, gnu-make

I need to design a make file which will run multiple (similarly named) programs in succession. It also needs to be portable since it will be used on both CentOS and Solaris (non-GNU) systems. I've never really worked with loops in a makefile before. Here's my attempt below. Unfortunately, it only seems to execute the first program.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall #-Werror

SRCS  := $(wildcard *.c)
PROGS := $(SRCS:.c=)
OBJS  := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(PROGS)

run:    $(PROGS)
    $(foreach prog, $(PROGS), ./$(prog))

clean: $(PROGS)
    rm $(PROGS)
```

Here's the result of running `make run` from the terminal

```
./prog-14  ./prog-17  ./prog-20  ./prog-13  ./prog-18  ./prog-06  ./prog-07  ./prog-04  ./prog-19  ./prog-11  ./prog-03  ./prog-08  ./prog-12  ./prog-16  ./prog-21  ./prog-01  ./prog-10  ./prog-15  ./prog-05  ./prog-09  ./prog-02
in program 14
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say Solaris, do you mean you're using Solaris `make`?  Or are you using GNU make on Solaris?

Why are you trying to use make functions?  If you want to be completely portable, you have to use the shell for looping:

```
run: $(PROGS)
        for p in $(PROGS); do ./$$p; done
```

If you are using GNU make on Solaris you can use GNU make pattern rules to do this in a more "make-like" way:

```
run: $(PROGS:%=run-%)

run-%: %
        ./$<

.PHONY: run $(PROGS:%=run-%)
```

Comment: I'll be using Solaris make (as part of the hw assignment, it's not my choice)

Comment: The first solution works like a charm, thanks a lot! Now, why was my loop only executing the first program (with GNU make)?

Comment: @audiFanatic: because the GNU make `foreach` function concatenates all the foreach'd strings together with a space in between them (rather than, say, a newline or semicolon). So the first program gets the list of other programs as command line arguments. You'd need to use both `foreach` and `shell` to execute every program, but @MadScientist's solution is much better.

Comment: You could use a `foreach` with a semicolon between them, like this: `$(foreach prog,$(PROGS),./$(prog) ;)` and you don't need `shell`; it's virtually always a really bad idea to use the `shell` function inside a recipe.  However, _all_ these functions are only available in GNU make; they are completely non-portable and will fail in Solaris `make`.